# NodeJS can't find python: gyp ERR! find Python

Tags: linux, bash, python, raspberry-pi, node.js

I'm trying to run a script but nodejs can't find python for some reason. I have tried reinstalling python, reinstalling nodejs, reinstalling my OS, running (and rebooting afterwards): `export PYTHON="$(which python)"`, `export PYTHON="$(which python3)"` (which python does return the right path), `npm config set python /usr/bin/python3.9`, `npm config set python "/usr/bin/python3.9"` and `export PYTHONPATH="$(which python)"` but nothing has worked. I'm running 64 bit lite raspberry OS off a raspberry pi 4. I installed nodejs and python with sudo apt install python/npm/nodejs. [Context](https://github.com/Hubro/clipface/discussions/50)

[Error](https://pastebin.com/yRHYLunS)

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -xe

cd client
rm -rf .next
yarn
yarn build 
cd ..

bash ./bundle-client.sh
docker build --network=host -t clipface:latest .
rm client/docker-bundle.tgz
```

I tried adding --python="/usr/bin/python3.9" to line 7 and 8 but it makes no difference. I can't add it to line 12 because docker doesn't have a --python switch. Line 12 is when the error occurs

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

# App setup

ADD client/docker-bundle.tgz /

WORKDIR /app

RUN yarn --prod

# Configuration

ENV NODE_CONFIG_DIR=/config
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV PORT 80
EXPOSE 80
VOLUME /clips
VOLUME /config

CMD yarn start -p ${PORT}
```

New errors after adding `RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python` to Dockerfile: https://pastebin.com/eKPZzPSk

Comment: `gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python` have you tried that?

Comment: I edited the post to include the script.

I tried adding `--python="/usr/bin/python3.9"` to line 7 and 8 but it makes no difference. I can't add it to line 12 because docker doesn't have a --python switch. Line 12 is when the error occurs

Comment: I tried adding the python switch to `RUN yarn --prod` in the dockerfile as that is more specifically where it fails but I still get the same error